# Yocto - ERROR: Layer directory '\' does not exist

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am very new to Yocto.

The aim is to customize a build for a particular embedded device. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 as the build host. An SDK has already been provided for the device with all the Yocto layers etc. which I cloned, and now following instructions.

When I get to the stage to actually run the build with command as follows `bitbake tr-bundle-sdk`

I receive the following error :

```
ERROR: Server log for this session (/home/tr-build/build/bitbake-cookerdaemon.log):
--- Starting bitbake server pid 3515 at 2021-05-15 20:03:38.165589 ---
ERROR: Layer directory '\' does not exist! Please check BBLAYERS in /home/tr-build/build/conf/bblayers.conf
```

I would think that this would be simple to resolve. However, when I check the bblayers.conf file as below, nothing is obvious :

```
# Do not edit! This file is managed automatically by tr-build-env.

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \\
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/openembedded-core/meta \\
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \\
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \\
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \\
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-python \\
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-webserver \\
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-rauc \\
  "
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Am I missing something obvious here? Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Do not edit! This file is managed automatically by tr-build-env.

BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
BBFILES ?= ""

BBLAYERS ?= " \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/openembedded-core/meta \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-openembedded/meta-webserver \
  ${TOPDIR}/../layers/meta-rauc \
  "
```

Comment: Thanks. So the \\ is clearly a typo from the developers of the SDK do you think?

Comment: It appears so. Someone's editor messed it up it seems. Make a PR.